How to wrap TabbedContent Tabs list display in python textual?
I'm working with Textual, a great TUI framework in python.
I need to display many tabs, which each contain wide data tables. I'd like the tab list to display fully within the screen width (wrapping if needed).
However, I would like the DataTables to still be displayed at full width with a horizontal scroll (just mentioning this as a constraint - I don't want to end up truncating the entire app width).
I have not figured out how to apply styles to accomplish this, or if it is even possible. I've tried targeting all the subcomponents for the TabbedContent that seem like they may contain the display for the tab list, but these appear to have no effect.
Example:
class TooManyTabsApp(App):
    CSS_TARGETS = [
        "ContentTabs",
        "#tabs-list",
        "#tabs-list-bar",
        "#tabs-scroll",
        "Tabs",
        "TabPane",
        "ContentSwitcher",
        "TabbedContent"
    ]

    CSS = f"""
        {CSS_TARGETS[0]} {{
            max-width: 100vw;
        }}
    """

    def compose(self):
        columns = [f"Loooooong column {i}" for i in range(10)]

        with TabbedContent():
            for i in range(10):
                with TabPane(f"Loooooong Tab {i}"):
                    dt = DataTable()
                    dt.add_columns(*columns)
                    yield dt

    def on_mount(self):
        self.log(self.css_tree)

def main():
    app = TooManyTabsApp()
    app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()

Regardless of the target, the display I get continues to extend off the screen:

My desired view would look something like:
Looooooong Tab 0 | Looooooong Tab 1 | Looooooong Tab 2 | Looooooong Tab 3 |
Looooooong Tab 4 | Looooooong Tab 5 | Looooooong Tab 6 | Looooooong Tab 7 |
Looooooong Tab 8 | Looooooong Tab 9 |

<selected pane content>

Am I missing something here? I would appreciate any pointers.

The tabs aren't designed to wrap. They already take 100% of the width, and will scroll to show the currently selected tab.
I'm curious what behavior you wanted if there are too many tabs to fit. Presumably the tabs would word wrap? So the first tab would be "Looooong\nTab\n0" on three lines?

Got it, thanks! that makes sense - so if I understand, there is sort of a 'view' of the tabs which is already at 100% width, which is why my CSS had no effect.

My hope was for something like flex-wrap in CSS, where instead of the tabs scrolling off the edges of the Tabs 'view', I could get the tabs themselves to wrap to subsequent lines:
| Tab 4 | Tab 5 |```
The goal would be to show the user all the available tabs at once. Helpful to know I was barking up the wrong tree though!

That's exactly right. If you add a feature request to the Textual repository, I'm sure the devs will consider it for a future version.
